# How do I get a controller's URL from a view in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url

Let say I am at my View loaded by my controller named Book.

Is there any way for me to get my controller’s URL at View instead of manually typing:

```
echo base_url('book');
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To return the current controller, you can use.

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
```

Equally, if you wanted to return the current method, then you could use:

```
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't you just do this: `echo current_url();`

Comment: When I echo current_url(); it will show all the URL, included my class, my method and its parameter. And I only need the class. :)

Comment: Oh in that case you can just echo `$this->uri->segment(1);`

Comment: OH YES!, It's so OBVIOUS, Im so dumb T__T, have to think through before posting a question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Dont feel bad user, I have asked questions that were so horribly obvious I hid out for 6 months before asking another one

Comment: Ha I feel like I ask a dumb one about every other day.

Comment: Should be noted you need to load the URL Helper to use current_url() `$this->load->helper('url');`

Answer (score 0):

Late answer. Yes! The easier way is using `$this->uri->rsegment(n)` where n start from 1. By using rsegment rather than segment, you can avoid lost segment from route processing. This method should callable from view. Please refer to original uri library documentation.